# Elim a double negation hypothesis in Coq Proof Assistant?

Tags: logic, coq, proof

Could anyone explain to me why do we have to prove `~A` after `elim Ha.`?

Before "elim Ha"

```
1 subgoals
 A : Prop
 Ha : ~ ~ A
______________________________________(1/1)
 A
```

After

```
1 subgoals
 A : Prop
 Ha : ~ ~ A
______________________________________(1/1)
 ~ A
```

Is it right that means `~~A true, ~A true -> A true`?

In my knowledge, I only know the rule `~E` is `~A true, A true -> FalseHood true`

Comment: Are you trying to use classical logic? Because Coq's logic is intuitionistic by default. You'd need to add an axiom to make it classical. `~ ~ A /\ ~ A -> A` is intuitionistically valid, but `~ ~ A -> A` is not. `~ ~ (~ ~ A -> A)` is intuitionistically valid though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Coq, `~ P` is a notation for `P -> False`. If I'm not mistaken, using `elim` on an hypothesis of the shape `~ P` is the same as directly using `False_rect` (you can `Print False_rect` for more info) with `P` as an input.

Doing so, you say to Coq "I know that `P` holds, so using `P -> False`, I can derive a proof of `False`" which closes the goal by contradiction. That's why each time you `elim` a `~ P`, Coq asks you to provide a proof of `P`. In your case, `P` is `~ A`.